# debounce lodash how to reset the state so that the function is called after a while

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, lodash

how to make it so that when button clicks stop after a second, the _debounce function displays the inscription button clicks are over? Now it turns out that if you click all the time, then the function works all the time and accumulates

https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-leftpad-hex0ul

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import _debounce from "lodash/debounce";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    _debounce(() => console.log("counter increment is widespread"), 1000)();
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>you clicked {count} </p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Click on me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you want the ui update after multiple click

Comment: I want this part to be called after 1 second when the clicks are finished

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    _debounce(() => console.log("counter increment is widespread"), 1000)();
  }, [count]);

Comment: You can use `setTimeout` to delay the update.

Comment: @Виктория you want the count to increment only once(within 1 second) no matter how many times the button is clicked right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useMemo` and debounced state

[codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-hugle-7twv13?file=/src/App.js:0-646)

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback, useMemo } from "react";

import _debounce from "lodash/debounce";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [debouncedCount, setDebouncedCount] = useState(0);

  const updateCount = useMemo(() => {
    return _debounce((val) => {
      setCount(val);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  const update = (value) => {
    updateCount(value);
    setDebouncedCount(value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>you clicked {count} </p>
      <button onClick={() => update(debouncedCount + 1)}>Click on me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correct this code will work.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import _debounce from "lodash/debounce";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  
  const handleCount = _debounce((count) => {
    setCount(count)
  }, 1000)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>you clicked {count} </p>
      <button onClick={() => handleCount(count+1)}>Click on me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```